# Is it ok to use the Frequent adverbs eg. always,often,usually,etc in past tense?

Tags: grammar

Is it OK to use the 'frequent' adverbs e.g. always, often, usually, etc. in the past tense? For example:

> She always went to park.
>   She usually ate bananas.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of where you think it may NOT be used?

Comment: May be i should use "would"  instead of past form of verb.For example "She would always go to the park".Does it make any change in meaning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is totally ok. The only think that you would want to stray away from is making bold statements with Always that could upset others. She always misbehaved. He always was considered the bad kid. etc.